# ogr2ogr: Create CSV with strings wrapped in double quotes

Tags: gdal, ogr, csv, ogr2ogr

Is there a way to force ogr2ogr to wrap string-column values with double-quotes?  I have a column with string values like "000010001", which OGR correctly interprets as a string when writing to CSV.  However, Excel converts that value to a numeric 10001 when parsing the CSV, due to a lack double-quotes wrapping the value.

Comment: @Luke - it's not me that's doing the Excel import.  It downstream users that I have no personal contact with.  But I understand your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs for [`ogr2ogr`](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) and the [CSV driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html) it doesn't look possible to specify quoting text fields on output.

You might like to try converting to [XLSX format](http://www.gdal.org/drv_xlsx.html):

```
ogr2ogr -f XLSX test.xlsx test.csv
```

Or you can force quotes using [OGR SQL](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html), but be aware they get quoted again on output:

```
$ ogr2ogr -sql "select concat('\"', a, '\"') as A, B, C from test" -f csv /vsistdout/ test.csv
A,B,C
"""0123""",12,a
"""0234""",123,b
"""2345""",1234,c
"""0101""",12345,d
```

if you are using a Mac/Linux PC you can strip the triple double quotes by piping to sed (or awk or use bash variable manipulation)

```
$ ogr2ogr -sql "select concat('\"', a, '\"') as A, B, C from test" -f csv /vsistdout/ test.csv | sed -e 's/\"\"\"/\"/g'
A,B,C
"0123",12,a
"0234",123,b
"2345",1234,c
"0101",12345,d
```